# Cannot access authenticated MongoDB collection from ReactiveMongo Play app

Tags: mongodb, play-reactivemongo

I have a MongoDB server where I have enabled authentication and created users with DB-specific permissions.  The user for this app is defined as shown below i.e. geoAdmin has read, readWrite and dbOwner permissions for the relevant database:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.0
connecting to: 192.168.2.89/test
> use geo_db
switched to db geo_db
> db.getUser("geoAdmin")
{
    "_id" : "geo_db.geoAdmin",
    "user" : "geoAdmin",
    "db" : "geo_db",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "read",
            "db" : "geo_db"
        },
        {
            "role" : "dbOwner",
            "db" : "geo_db"
        },
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "geo_db"
        }
    ]
}
```

The following query works OK i.e. connecting to the remote server from my local mongo client:

```
mint:~ $ mongo 192.168.2.89:27017 -u geoAdmin -p secret --authenticationDatabase geo_db
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.0
connecting to: 192.168.2.89/test
> use geo_db
switched to db geo_db
>  db.LAD_DEC_2013_GB_BFE.findOne({},{'properties.LAD13NM':1})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54ffe2824f0787ec1293017f"),
    "properties" : {
        "LAD13NM" : "Hartlepool"
    }
}
```

I then connect to the same remote host from a ReactiveMongo Play app on the same local client, with this URL in the app config file:

```
# ReactiveMongo
mongodb.uri = "mongodb://geoAdmin:secret@192.168.2.89:27017/geo_db"
```

But when my app tries to read from the same collection, I get a MongoDB "code = 13" error:

```
[DetailedDatabaseException: DatabaseException['not authorized for query on geo_db.LAD_DEC_2013_GB_BFE' (code = 13)]]
```

The app works fine if I connect to a local MongoDB which does not have authentication enabled.

Any ideas what might be going wrong here?

Comment: It looks like the latest release of ReactiveMongo that is available at the moment (0.10, Dec-2013) pre-dates MongoDB 3.0. I suspect that means it does not yet have support for the new [SCRAM-SHA-1](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-scram/) default authentication or for listing collections in WiredTiger. It looks like WiredTiger support has been committed to [master](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo/commits/master) but on quick skim I don't see any mention of 3.0-compatible authentication.

Comment: There's a possible workaround of using the older MONGODB-CR authentication in MongoDB 3.0 (although a better fix would be to update the driver). For an example of how to downgrade authSchema to test if this is indeed the problem, see this [discussion on the mongodb-user group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-user/4-nbyYch7bA/S3UHEfVgkesJ).

Comment: Thanks for the extra info.  I tried the authSchema thing but it doesn't seem to work for me.  I guess I'll just have to live without authentication (this is just a demo app) until ReactiveMongo catches up.  Or I could downgrade to MongoDB 2.8 of course.

Comment: You can give a try to the snapshot mentionned on the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/reactivemongo/gC5vLErbq8E).

Comment: FYI, MongoDB 2.8 only existed as release candidates; the final release was [renamed to MongoDB 3.0](http://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/renaming-our-upcoming-release-mongodb-30). The production release series prior to Mongo 3.0.x is 2.6.x.

Comment: @Stennie i am seeing the same issue. I tried on mongodb 2.6.8 but still getting the same error. Does reactivemongo work with auth enabled?

Answer (score 2):

ReactiveMongo 0.11.7.play23 is *supporting* mongo 3.0 auth-protocols, but is still using the old as default.

With ReactiveMongo 0.11.7.play23 -plugin, you can make it authenticate with mongo 3.0, by adding "?authMode=scram-sha1" to the end of your mongodb.uri.
E.g.:

```
mongodb.uri = "mongodb://geoAdmin:secret@192.168.2.89:27017/geo_db?authMode=scram-sha1"
```

Answer (score 1):

mongo 2.6 uses MONGODB-CR auth protocol and 3.0 uses MONGODB-SHA-1 by default

reactivemongo use MONGODB-CR auth protocol(not sure)

downgrade mongodb 3.0 auth mechanisms to MONGODB-CR

1. login mongo noauth
2. remove all user
3. update the version document for the authSchema.

ex.

```
db.getSiblingDB("admin").system.users.remove( {} )
db.getSiblingDB("admin").system.version.update(
   { _id: "authSchema" },
   { $set: { currentVersion: 3 } }
);
```

add authSource parameter to mongodb url
ex.

```
mongodb.uri = "mongodb://geoAdmin:secret@192.168.2.89:27017/geo_db?authSource=geo_db"
```